# Почему не на всех девайсах определяется местоположение?

Tags: android, java, gps

Добрый вечер! Перелопатил всю документацию по `LocacionListener`, а так же пересмотрел и перепробовал различные реализации, но каждый раз при тестах на разных устройствах, появляются такие, на которых все печально. 
Подскажите в чем проблема может быть? Я уже не понимаю. Например проблемы были на `Samsung Galaxy S1, Galaxy fit, htc one v, HTC Incredible S,  Pipo Smart` S1 и др. Не понимаю в чем дело. Сам тестирую все на `Galaxy S3`.
На данный момент я использую реализацию вот такую(а были и другие).

```
public class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener
{

    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private String mCurrentProvider;
    private boolean mLocationEnabled = false;
    private Location mLocation = null;
    private LocationListener locationListener;
    //реализация интерфейса Runnable которая вызовет нужные методы в UI потоке
    private LocationRunnable runnable = null;

    public LocationListener(Context context, LocationRunnable runnable)
    {
        this.runnable = runnable;
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    }

    public boolean enableMyLocation()
    {
        mLocationEnabled = true;
        List<String> mProviders = mLocationManager.getProviders(true);

        if (mProviders.size() > 0)
        {

            locationListener = this;

            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, locationListener);

            if(mProviders.contains( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) && mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
                mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, locationListener);

        }

        //запускаем фоновый процесс, который отсчитает, что прошло 30 секунд
        new TimeOut().execute();
        return false;
    }

    private class TimeOut extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            //тут отсчитываем 30 секунд и если метод onLocationChanged еще не вызывался, то запустим runnable
            long sec = System.currentTimeMillis();
            //тут стал проверять locationChanged которая с моификтором volatile
            while (!locationChanged == null && System.currentTimeMillis() - sec < 30 * 1000)
            {

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void p)
        {
            if (!locationChanged)
            {
                runnable.setLocation(mLocation);
                runnable.run();
            }

            //откажемся от обновлений
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
        }
    }

    // тут сделал как сказали, и отказался от использования в фоновом потоке locztion
    private volatile boolean locationChanged = false;

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        //если мы определили местоположение то вызовем изменения в UI
        mLocation = location;
        locationChanged = true;
        runnable.setLocation(location);
        runnable.run();

        //откажемся от обновлений
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
    }

}
```

**UPD:** отказался от определения по GPS, в фоновом потоке перестал обращаться к mLocation, вместо этого проверяю переменную типа boolean  с модификатором volatile. Эффекта от проделанных действий  - ноль.

Comment: может просто gps не успевает подключиться? Особенно, если тестируете в помещение.

плюс ко всему, этот код

    while (mLocation == null && System.currentTimeMillis() - sec < 30 * 1000)
    {}

плохой. он может работать не так, как Вам кажется. нужно как минимум mLocation  объявлять с модификатором `volatile`. а по хорошему - прицепить полноценную синхронизацию.

Comment: дело в том, что mLocation читается в одном потоке, а пишется в другом. Компилятор может один раз проверить значение и перестать проверять.

Comment: @KoVadim, этого достаточно будет?

            synchronized (mLocation)
            {
                long sec = System.currentTimeMillis();
                //time out 30 sec
                while (mLocation == null && System.currentTimeMillis() - sec < 10 * 1000)
                {

                }
            }

Comment: в onLocationChanged также нужно. Но я все таки думаю, что у Вас просто gps очень долго подключается, и это основная причина.

Comment: @KoVadim, да и проблема совсем не в этом. Я выжидаю 30 секунд, а затем если метод onLocationChanged не был вызван, в котором выполняется runnable.run(), выполняю его, а если вызывался, то все ок. Проблемы из-за синхронизация и доступ к переменным из других потоков тут маловероятны. Ведь onLocationChanged не вызывается за эти 30 секунда, даже если не использовать gps

Comment: @KoVadim, может вы предложите свой вариант реализации или ткнете меня носом, чтобы добиться того, что я хочу?